# Find differential for $A \mapsto A^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ by rule $A \mapsto A^2$. How to find $\mathrm{d}f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: if $A\in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ then for any $n\times n$ matrix $H$, you get $$f(A+H)- f(A) = AH+HA + H^2.$$

Comment: I had got this, but i have no idea how to transform $AH+HA$ into something like $2AH$(in case $A = E$)

Comment: @user2715119 That part is easy (I assume $E$ means the identity matrix).  If $A = E$, then $AH = HA$ no matter what $H$ happens to be.

Comment: Or i should compute elements of $AH+HA$ and then differential is $\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{i,k}h_{k,j}+a_{k,j}h_{i,k}) \}_{i,j}$?
It's seems so terrible..

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but if $A$ is not $E$ why $df$ still $2AH$?

Comment: @user2715119 it is **not** still $2AH$.  It will be $AH + HA$, which is distinct.

Comment: Oh lol i was so stupid, it's obvious!
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* You could consider
$$
(A+H)^2-A^2=(A^2+A\cdot H+H\cdot A+H^2)-A^2=A\cdot H+H\cdot A+o(||H||).
$$